# display always the right MDX (sub)total in the client-application (eg Excel)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I can't figure it out! (CustomRollUpColumn??, or some custom made MDX calculated thing)

My problem: I have a dimension TypeOfRow who's function it is to display the ... well yes ... type of row. I'm working in the financial sector and, always, need to provide the ultimate result ==>> The Total Contribution. I read, amongst others, the article of Martin Mason ( http://martinmason.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/the-ssas-financial-cubepart-1ragged-hierarchies/ ) and designed the dimension as a "Naturalized Parent-Child Hierarchy".

The dimension, 5 levels, I designed for this solution is (simplyfied):

•+/+ Revenue (several types of)

•-/- Cost (several types of)

•= Total Contribution

A user requirement is that the "Total Contribution" always display the "Total Contribution" even if any the Revenue- or  Cost types are filtered out.

My question: is this possible showing the total of a dimension without showing all the members (in Excel but I hope to configure this in SSAS 2008R2)?

many thanks in advance, - Leon